# Bootstrap the right way to implement logo/text above navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, seo

I wanted to put text or image logo above navbar. Got it working with responsive utilities. The question is, Is that the right way? The problem is text/logo is 2 times mentioned on page. First in .master-logo and second in .navbar-brand.

1. Does it affect search engine optimization?
2. Is there other way to implement this?

Code to better understanding:

```
<header id="site-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="master-logo hidden-xs">
            Brand
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix up the logo with H1 tag.

Search engines don't evaluate your logo that much. They focus on the page title and the H1 Tag.